# Can't Autowire DefaultTokenService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am facing a problem in a simple project, I am just trying to autowire the DefaultTokenService class but when the application starts, this raise the next exception:

Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices

```html
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        ... 

        @Autowired
 private DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices;

        ...

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
 }

        ...

}
```

I am using spring-boot: 1.3.5.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE 1 - Stacktrace added: **

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springfr
amework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframe
work.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'socialApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices com.example.SocialApplication.defaultTokenServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of t
ype [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.fact
ory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                           
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                               
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                           
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                            
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                             
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                               
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                           
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                       
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                      
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                    
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                     
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4658) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5277) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                              
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                                           
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]                                                                                                                
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                                               
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                        
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                        
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                                                                  
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.s
pringframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'socialApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire 
field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices com.example.SocialApplication.defaultTokenServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying be
an of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.bea
ns.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                           
        ... 31 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'socialApplication': Injection of au
towired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices com.example.SocialApplicatio
n.defaultTokenServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected
 at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                    
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                            
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                            
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1029) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                         
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                       
        ... 33 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'socialApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices com.example.SocialApplication.defaultTokenServices; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExceptio
n: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.
springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                                                                                                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                           
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                               
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                           
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                             
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                             
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:53) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.
jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                                           
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                         
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]                                                                                                                                                                      
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                              
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                       
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                         
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242) ~[spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                   
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                            
        ... 37 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices com.example.SocialApplication.defaultTokenServices; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as au
towire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                                                          
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                           
        ... 59 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies 
as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                                                         
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]                        
        ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to manually add DefaultTokenServices bean.
Try create your own `@Bean` of type `DefaultTokenServices`. For example, like that:

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Bean
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
    final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(-1);

    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    return defaultTokenServices;
}
```

Comment: Hi Solorad thank you for reply, I have tried for code but it does not solve the problem, it is sill asking for an implemented bean.

Comment: I simplified `DefaultTokenServices`  creation and its 100% works for me. Please, provide your stack trace.

Comment: Replace your `@Autowired` field with `@Bean` methods.

Comment: @Solorad could you please help me with this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648192/spring-boot-oauth2-extending-defaulttokenservices