# Spring Boot Oauth2 Extending DefaultTokenServices

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, autowired, spring-security-oauth2

I have an OAuth2 implementation that is working fine for the grant type = password. Now I need to add a logic of restricting the same user/password combination to be allowed to login again if the user is logged in earlier.
For that, I researched and figured that I to create a new class (MyDefaultTokenService) that extends the DefaultTokenServices class and then add my logic in the overriden createAccessToken method. But for some reason when I debug and test, I dont hit the breakpoints placed in MyDefaultTokenService class. It always hits the Springboot's DefaultTokenServices class. I dont know where I am going wrong, could somebody please.

AuthorizationConfiguration.java

```
    package com.company.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.TokenRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancerChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

import com.alcord.enums.Authorities;
import com.alcord.model.Account;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
        implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
    private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "clientid";
    private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
    private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "tokenValidityInSeconds";

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID)).scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_DRIVER.name(),
                        Authorities.ROLE_PASSENGER.name())
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
                .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET)).accessTokenValiditySeconds(
                        propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 1800));
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        MyTokenService tokenService = new MyTokenService();
        tokenService.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        tokenService.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenService.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
        return tokenService;
    }

    class MyTokenService extends DefaultTokenServices {

        public MyTokenService() {
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String accessToken) {
            return super.readAccessToken(accessToken);
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            OAuth2AccessToken token = super.createAccessToken(authentication);
            Account account = (Account) authentication.getPrincipal();
            // This is where I will add my logic when it hits the breakpoint.
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken refreshAccessToken(String refreshTokenValue, TokenRequest tokenRequest)
                throws AuthenticationException {

            OAuth2AccessToken token = super.refreshAccessToken(refreshTokenValue, tokenRequest);
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

Resource Server Configuration

```
package com.company.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

import com.alcord.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.alcord.security.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // The DefaultTokenServices bean provided at the AuthorizationConfig
    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    // The TokenStore bean provided at the AuthorizationConfig
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler).and().csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/v1/test/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices).tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId("oauth2_id");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to this: needed a call to `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.tokenServices` in the `configure` method.

```java
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer()));
    endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .tokenServices(tokenServices()) // missed this!
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be helpful if you add link for an example.