# can we maintain more than one access token for one authentication object(credential) in jdbcTokenStore

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I want to maintain more than one access tokens for same credentials of a user is it possible for us to override createAccessToken method of DefaultTokenServices to do that.

All I want is that when an access token for a user expires from one device ,it should not affect the access token of the same user logged in from other device(ie maintain as many access token for a user, as the number of logins of that user)

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate bit more on what exactly you need to achieve? Irrespective of client you should be allowed to authenticate concurrently. Spring security allows maximumSessions property to allow multiple sessions
ex:

```
http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(2)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

Extending **DefaultTokenService** is very much possible, please refer [Spring Boot Oauth2 Extending DefaultTokenServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648192/spring-boot-oauth2-extending-defaulttokenservices).

Comment: All I want is that when an access token for a user expires from one device ,it should not affect the access token of the same user logged in from other device(ie maintain as many access token for a user, as the number of logins of that user)